# Mock objects for Grepping a binary file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

For a certain scenario, we grep a binary file for a certain manufacturer string in Ruby. I would like to create the associated Mock object in Rspec.
I tried the following but that did not help:

```
  File.stub!(:exist?).with(<binary_file>).and_return(true)
  File.stub!(:read?).with(<binary_file>).and_return('XYZ')
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the `!` from `#stub`, it is not used in newer versions of RSpec.  Secondly, `stub(:read?)` should be `stub(:read)`, since it is not a predicate method.

Without seeing the implementation code, those changes should put you in the right direction.

That said, where it is avoidable, I tend to disagree with stubbing class methods like this, since there is a pretty big risk of state leakage through tests.  I would instead design the component that does the searching in the file to accept an instance of `IO`, then it becomes much easier to pass in a mock object that is entirely disposable.

Comment: I fixed the code as :

      File.stub(:exist?).with('/sys/firmware/dmi/entries/1-0/raw').and_return(true)

      File.stub(:read).with('/sys/firmware/dmi/entries/1-0/raw').and_return('xyz')

Although it still does not work for me. I also try to sudo before this.